# Upload zip file with fog to google storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-storage, fog

In a rails 4 app, I have trouble to upload zip into google storage using fog. I have no problem with image but kmz file ( zip) doesn't work

I use gem 'fog-google'

It's seams to be properly configure into the 'config/initializers/initialiserfog_cloud_storage.rb'

```
config = Rails.application.config.x.settings["cloud_storage"]
FogStorage = Fog::Storage.new(
   provider: "Google",
   google_storage_access_key_id:     config["access_key_id"],
   google_storage_secret_access_key: config["secret_access_key"]
)

StorageBucket = FogStorage.directories.new key: config["bucket"]
```

I have a view for editing a model that content a form that content 2 file field.

"app/views/customer_projets/create_doc.html.erb"

```
    <%= form_tag(update_ge_image_path(@customer_project.id),method: :put, multipart: :true) do%>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
       <%= file_field_tag "google_earth_image", class: "form-control", multipart: true %>
       <%= submit_tag 'Télécharge', class: 'button' %>
      </div>
    <% end%>

    <%= form_tag(update_ge_file_path(@customer_project.id),method: :put, multipart: :true) do%>
     <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <%= file_field_tag "kmz_fichier", class: "form-control", multipart: true %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Télécharge', class: 'button' %>
     </div>
    <% end%>
```

I have this parameter inside my controler:
"app/controller/customer_projet_controler.rb"

```
def update_ge_image
    @customer_project = CustomerProject.find(params[:id])
    @customer_project.google_earth_image = params[:google_earth_image]

    if @customer_project.save
        redirect_to create_doc_path(:id => @customer_project.id), notice: "Image mise à jour"
    else
        redirect_to create_doc_path(:id => @customer_project.id), notice: "Probleme de telechargement"
    end

end

def update_ge_file
    @customer_project = CustomerProject.find(params[:id])
    @customer_project.kmz_fichier = params["kmz_fichier"]

    if @customer_project.save
        redirect_to create_doc_path(:id => @customer_project.id), notice: "kmz mise à jour"
    else
        redirect_to create_doc_path(:id => @customer_project.id), notice: "Probleme de telechargement"
    end

end
def customer_project_params
  params.require(:society).permit( ... :google_earth_path,:google_earth_image, :kmz_path, :kmz_fichier)
end
```

and I have the following model for customer_projet
in "app/models.customer_project.rb"

```
def upload_image(folder_name,file)
    folder = folder_name
    if !Rails.env.production?  
        folder = "#{folder_name}_test"
    end
    bucket_file = StorageBucket.files.new(
      key: "#{folder}/customer_project_#{id}/#{file.original_filename}",
      body: file.read,
      public: true
    )

    bucket_file.save 

    return bucket_file.public_url
end

#### upload kmz

# [START upload]
after_create :upload_kmz, if: :kmz_fichier
def upload_kmz
    public_url = upload_image("kmz_fichier",kmz_fichier)

    update_columns kmz_path: public_url
end
# [END upload]
# [START delete]
before_destroy :delete_kmz, if: :kmz_path

def delete_kmz
    delete_image(kmz_path)
end
# [END delete]
# [START update]
before_update :update_kmz, if: :kmz_fichier

def update_kmz

    delete_kmz if kmz_path?
    upload_kmz
end
# [END update]  

##### upload image

# [START upload]
after_create :upload_image_ge, if: :google_earth_image
def upload_image_ge

    public_url = upload_image("google_earth_image",google_earth_image)
    update_columns google_earth_path: public_url
end
# [END upload]
# [START delete]
before_destroy :delete_image_ge, if: :google_earth_path

def delete_image_ge
    delete_image(google_earth_path)
end
# [END delete]
# [START update]
before_update :update_image_ge, if: :google_earth_image

def update_image_ge
    delete_image_ge if google_earth_path?
    upload_image_ge
end
```

The upload of the image work perfectly but the upload of the kmz (zip) create a 0kO file inside the bucket.

I haven't any idea why ?

Thanks for your help.

```
####EDIT : SOLUTION ######
```

inside controller, I was using params["kmz_fichier"] instead of params[:kmz_fichier]